# Conditional expected value of Ito integral

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, conditional-expectation, stochastic-integrals

Let $0<\sigma_s<M$ be a bounded continuous stochastic process independent from a Brownian motion $W$. Let $\mathcal{F}_{\sigma}$ be the sigma-algebra generated by $\left\{\sigma_s|0\leq s\leq 1\right\}$.

I need to prove that

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\int_0^1\sigma_s\,dW_s\right)^k\left|\right.\mathcal{F}_{\sigma}\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[U^k\right]\left(\int_0^1\sigma_s^2\,ds\right)^{\frac{k}{2}}
$$ 
where $U\stackrel{d}{=}\text{N}\left(0,1\right)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $\sigma$ is bounded and continuous, it is not difficult to see that

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \sigma_{j/n} (W_{(j+1)/n}-W_{j/n}) \xrightarrow[]{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 \sigma_s \, dW_s \quad \text{in probability.} \tag{$\star$}$$

This implies

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E} \left( \exp \left[ i \xi \int_0^1 \sigma_s \, dW_s \right] \mid \mathcal{F}_{\sigma} \right) &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E} \left( \exp \left[ i \xi \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \sigma_{j/n} (W_{(j+1)/n}-W_{j/n}) \right] \mid \mathcal{F}_{\sigma} \right) \\ &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E} \left( \prod_{j=0}^{n-1} \exp \left[ i \xi  \sigma_{j/n} (W_{(j+1)/n}-W_{j/n}) \right] \mid \mathcal{F}_{\sigma} \right). \end{align*}$$

Since $(W_t)_{t \in [0,1]}$ and $\mathcal{F}_{\sigma}$ are independent, we obtain that

$$\mathbb{E} \left( \exp \left[ i \xi \int_0^1 \sigma_s \, dW_s \right] \mid \mathcal{F}_{\sigma} \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E} \left( \prod_{j=0}^{n-1} \exp \left( i \xi x_j (W_{(j+1)/n}-W_{j/n}) \right) \right] \bigg|_{x_j = \sigma_{j/n}};$$

using that $W_{(j+1)/n}-W_{j/n} \sim N(0,1/n$, $j=0,\ldots,n-1$ are independent, we find that

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E} \left( \exp \left[ i \xi \int_0^1 \sigma_s \, dW_s \right] \mid \mathcal{F}_{\sigma} \right) &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{j=0}^{n-1} \exp \left(-  \frac{1}{2}\xi^2 x_j^2 \frac{1}{n} \right)\bigg|_{x_j = \sigma_{j/n}} \\ &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \exp \left(- \frac{1}{2} \xi^2 \sum_{j=1}^n \sigma_{j/n}^2 \frac{1}{n} \right). \end{align*}$$

The expression on the right-hand side is a Riemann sum and therefore we conclude that

$$ \mathbb{E} \left( \exp \left[ i \xi \int_0^1 \sigma_s \, dW_s \right] \mid \mathcal{F}_{\sigma} \right) = \exp \left(-  \frac{1}{2}\xi^2 \int_0^1 \sigma_s^2 \, ds \right).  \tag{1}$$
Finally, we note that

$$i^k \mathbb{E}(X^k \mid \mathcal{F}) =\frac{d^k}{d\xi^k} \mathbb{E}(e^{i \xi X} \mid \mathcal{F}_{\sigma}) \bigg|_{\xi=0}$$

for any real-valued random variable $X$ such that $\mathbb{E}(|X|^k)<\infty$; differentiating $(1)$  $k$ times with respect to $\xi$ and evaluating at $\xi=0$ we conclude that

$$ \mathbb{E} \left( \left[  \int_0^1 \sigma_s \, dW_s \right]^k \mid \mathcal{F}_{\sigma} \right)=\mathbb{E}(U^k) \left( \int_0^1 \sigma_s^2 \, ds \right)^{k/2}$$

for $U \sim N(0,1)$.

**Remark:** Instead of calculating the conditional characteristic function, you can also show that the convergence in $(\star)$ holds in $L^k$ and then use this convergence to conclude that $$\mathbb{E} \left( \left( \int_0^1 \sigma_s \, dW_s \right)^k \mid \mathcal{F}_{\sigma} \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \left( \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \sigma_{j/n} (W_{(j+1)/n}-W_{j/n}) \right)^k \mid \mathcal{F}_{\sigma} \right);$$ then you can proceed with similar arguments as above.

Answer (score 0):

Briefly, the conditional distribution of $\int_0^1 \sigma_s\, dW_s$ given $\mathcal F_\sigma$ is normal with mean $0$ and variance $\int_0^1\sigma_s^2\,ds$.

Comment: even if true, this is more a hint than an answer, good for comment not more

Comment: "even if true"? (And anyway, the question seemed to be soliciting a hint.)

Comment: please take no offense I was just saying that a hint is more suited for a comment than an answer, and if you are making this an answer it would be nice to be more explicit and tell AlomstsureUser that Wiener integral and their properties are at stae here for a simpler (educated) approach even though saz proved those things in every details . Best regards