# Law of Ito Integral

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-integrals

Let $\sigma$ be an $\mathcal{F}_t$-adapted caglad stochastic process. Let $W$ be a Brownian motion independent of $\sigma$. Let $r>0$ be a strictly positive real number. How can I prove that 
$$
\left|\int_{0}^1\sigma_s\,dW_s\right|^r \stackrel{d}{=} \left|U\right|^r\,\left(\int_0^1\sigma_s^2\,ds\right)^{r/2},
$$ 
where $U\stackrel{d}{=}$ is a $\text{N}(0,1)$ gaussian variable?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2980321/36150)

Comment: @saz: Do you have any reference for proving that 
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \sigma_{j/n} (W_{(j+1)/n}-W_{j/n}) \xrightarrow[]{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 \sigma_s \, dW_s \quad\tag{$\star$}
$$
holds in $L^{r}$, for any $r>0$ ? The proof for $r=2$ is easily obtained with the Ito-isometry and implies convergence in $L^r$ for any $1\leq r<2$, but what about a generic $r>0$ not integer?

Comment: You can use the Burkholder-Davis-Gundy inequality to prove convergence in $L^r$ for any $r>0$.

Comment: @saz I think I have proved the $L^r$ convergence, nevertheless I am still confused. Since $r$ is not an integer, even if the $L^r$ convergence can be used to conclude that  
$$
\mathbb{E} \left( \left( \int_0^1 \sigma_s \, dW_s \right)^r \mid \mathcal{F}_{\sigma} \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}\left( \left( \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \sigma_{j/n} (W_{(j+1)/n}-W_{j/n}) \right)^r \mid \mathcal{F}_{\sigma} \right)
$$
how can we conclude that 
$$
\left|\int_{0}^1\sigma_s\,dW_s\right|^r \stackrel{d}{=} \left|U\right|^r\,\left(\int_0^1\sigma_s^2\,ds\right)^{r/2}\quad ?
$$

Comment: The idea is to calculate the characteristic function and to show that they are equal... that's essentially what I did in the answer which I linked in my first comment.

Comment: Yes, the problem now is the non-linearty. With $r=1$ is not particularly difficult, with $r>0$ generic one has to prove that
$$
\left|\sum_{k=0}^nf\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\,u_k\right|^r\stackrel{d}{\longrightarrow}\left|u\right|^k\,\left(\int_0^1f(s)^2\,ds\right)^{r/2}
$$
where $f$ is a Riemann-integrable function, $u_k$ are iid $N(0,1/n)$ gaussian random variable and $u$ is a $N(0,1)$-gaussian random variable.

Comment: Ah, sorry, that's not what I meant; I should have been more precise from the beginning. Using the linked answer, you can show that the random variables $$X := \int_0^1 \sigma(s) \, dW_s$$ and $$Y:= U \sqrt{\int_0^1 \sigma(s)^2 \, ds}$$ are equal in distribution for $U \sim N(0,1)$ independent from $\sigma$. This entails $$f(X) \stackrel{d}{=} f(Y)$$ for **any** function $f$; in particular, we can choose $f(x) = |x|^r$.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the important and helpful clarification. So the convergence in $L^r$ was not necessary in the end.